# how to split string according to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

How to check $str contains all valid words present in array $ar

```
<?php
 $ar = array('i','love','country','my','india');
 $str = 'iloveindia';
 // Something like 
 if($str is made from $ar){
     echo 'yes';
 }
 else {
     echo 'no';
 }
?>
```

Comment: You must do a for-loop and check with `strpos` for every element within your array

Comment: u want to match `'i'` also? one character

Comment: yes `'i'` should be taken separately `'i'` from `'india'` should not involve

Comment: did u used in_array?

Comment: it's giving output 'no' `<?php
$dictionary= array('i','love','indian','food','spicy');

if(in_array('indianfoodspicy',$dictionary)){
 echo 'yes';
}
else {
 echo 'no';
}
?>`

Comment: i shared a solution chk now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) within `foreach` loop like:

```
$ar = array('i','love','country','my','india');
$str = 'iloveindia';

foreach ($ar as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($str,$value) !== false) {
        echo $value. ' >> yes <br/>';
    }
    else{
        echo $value .' >> no <br/>';
    }   
}
```

**Result:**

```
i >> yes 
love >> yes 
country >> no 
my >> no 
india >> yes
```

**Side Note:** Now you can change your logic as you need either need to check 1 word or all from an array.